# there is no agent/cloud that matches this assignment - jenkins error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

while i am trying to create a job , i am trying to assign a slave node but i am getting the error as " there is no agent that matches this assignment". but i created a node called " Linux_slave1" and my Jenkins was able to connect to the slave.
[image: error when configuring the job]
[image: Jenkins communicating to Linux_slave1]

Comment: as you see the error is talking about node called 'l'. This happened as you typed in the node name linux_slave1.  Once fully typed, it will  not show this error

Answer (score 6):

looks like a known issue with auto-completion of node labels. the label is shown correctly, but field validation gets the string you've actually entered (before it gets auto-completed) - that's why the error is shown. in general it's ok to save the job config  - the label will get resolved correctly during runtime. but if you want to be completely sure - put your cursor in the 'Label expression' text field, delete the trailing whitespace after 'linux_slave1' and then click outside the text field. validation error should disappear.